# different vars and ifs for different videos not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, var

I'm trying to create the function that if a key is pressed, a video appears. I have managed to do it for one key and it works fine:

```
 var video = document.getElementById('b1');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "b") {
     video.play(); video.currentTime = 0;
   }
});
```

But i want to do this for several different keys, (26 to be exact). I figured that what I needed to do was copy the same code and place it below, like this:

```
var video = document.getElementById('b1');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "b") {
     video.play(); video.currentTime = 0;
   }
});

var video = document.getElementById('d1');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "d") {
     video.play(); video.currentTime = 0;
   }
});
```

But i get the error: "'video' is already defined. Do not redeclare". I get that what's wrong is the composition of the code but I spent a while looking for the right way to do it and couldn't find it. Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: The big problem I see here is that if you don't isolate your variables, you'll end up polluting them. Specifically, by the time the event handlers are all defined, `video` will be the *last* video, so *all* event handlers will affect that one video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A variable can only have one value. When you reassign `video`, the old value is lost. When the event listeners fire, they'll use the last value that was assigned, so both keys will play the same video.

You can use different variables, or better would be to use an object that maps keys to videos.

```
var videos = {
    'b': document.getElementById('b1'),
    'd': document.getElementById('d1')
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    let video = videos[e.key];
    if (video) {
        video.play();
        video.currentTime = 0;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In fact if you write

```
var video = document.getElementById('b1');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "b") {
     video.play(); video.currentTime = 0;
   }
});

var video = document.getElementById('d1');   
document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
   if(e.key === "d") {
     video.play(); video.currentTime = 0;
   }
});
```

you are trying to define the variable video more than once, which is not allowed.
If you have multiple elements with different ids you should add different variable names.

Even better, you could do like:

```
setListener(elementID, keyToHaveEffect) {
   const videoElement = document.getElementById(elementID);
   if (e.key === keyToHaveEffect) {
      if (videoElement) {
         videoElement.play(); videoElement.currentTime = 0;
      }
   }
}
```

and then call it like

```
setListener('b1' , 'b')
```